# Calculating layer thickness in python

Tags: meteorology, wrf, python, netcdf

I have calculated the $∂θ_\varepsilon/∂z$ with 'Height', 'Latitude', 'Longitude' dimensions.

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
from wrf import (getvar)

eth = np.array(getvar(ncfile, "eth", timeidx=time))
z = np.array(getvar(ncfile, "z", timeidx=time, units="km")) 

deth = np.gradient(eth, axis=0)
dz = np.gradient(z, axis=0)
deth_dz = deth/dz

dthdz = xr.DataArray(data=deth_dz, dims=['Height', 'Latitude', 'Longitude'])
```

I would like to plot the horizontal depth or thickness (in km) of the `dthdz`.
It is a bit similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69009774/calculating-total-depth-of-a-variable) question. But when I do `dthdz.sum(dim='Height')`, I get very low depth values. I just want to know where I'm doing it wrong. Thank you!

Comment: For programming related questions unless you provide the dataset very few here can help you

Comment: Why not use MetPy's thickness API - https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/latest/api/generated/metpy.calc.thickness_hydrostatic.html ?

Comment: thanks @gansub! this uses conventional wrfout data. i tried the thickness_hydrostatic but it outputs in 1D. i was hoping to make a horizontal plot of the depth

Comment: Suggest you take this over to MetPy gitter and then ask the question over there.